# Yii2 - how to get a current quarter without the past quarter?

Tags: php, yii2

I've a problem here. I need to get a quarter of the year without the past quarter. F.e:

In my database I have a field `created_at`, which saves the timestamp of service created. I need to not involve those services, which was made in the past quarter. How should I do that?

I'm trying to write a SQL function like this to not involve those services, which was made in the past quarter:

```
$services= Service::find()
        ->where([         
            'client_service.created' => function ($model) {
                 return ceil(date('n') / 3) - 4;
```

But I guess I'm wrong. Thanks for any help.

Edited:

```
        $services= Service::find()
        ->select(['client.id as client_id'])
        ->joinWith('client')
        ->where([         
            'service.type' => Service::TYPE,
            'service.is_archived' => Service::ARCHIVED,])
        ->andWhere([
            'or',
            ['client_service.status' => ClientService::STATUS_NEGATIVE],
            [client_service.created' => function ($model) {
                 return ceil(date('n') / 3) - 4;]
```

Comment: Can u provide full query

Comment: I've just updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find `start` and `end` date of quarter

```
$date =  new \DateTime(); // Current Date and Time
$quarter_start = clone($date);

// Find the offset of months
$months_offset = ($date->format('m') - 1) % 3;

// Modify quarter date
$quarter_start->modify(" - " . $months_offset . " month")->modify("first day of this month");

$quarter_end = clone($quarter_start);
$quarter_end->modify("+ 3 month");

$startDate = $quarter_start->format('Y-m-d');
$endDate = $quarter_end->format('Y-m-d');
```

**Query**

```
$services= Service::find()
    ->select(['client.id as client_id'])
    ->joinWith('client')
    ->where([         
        'service.type' => Service::TYPE,
        'service.is_archived' => Service::ARCHIVED,])
    ->andWhere([
        'or',
        ['client_service.status' => ClientService::STATUS_NEGATIVE],
        ['between', 'date_format(FROM_UNIXTIME(client_service.created), "%Y-%m-%d")', $startDate, $endDate]
```

You can also use mysql [Quarter()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_quarter) to achieve the result.

Answer (score 2):

You are storing timestemp in db for service date , we can find current Quarter start date and end date from current month and use in query.

```
     $current_month = date('m');
     $current_year = date('Y');
     if($current_month>=1 && $current_month<=3)
     {
       $start_date = strtotime($current_year.'-01-01 00:00:00');  
       $end_date = strtotime($current_year.'-03-31 23:59:59');  
     }
     else  if($current_month>=4 && $current_month<=6)
     {
       $start_date = strtotime($current_year.'-04-01 00:00:00');
       $end_date = strtotime($current_year.'-06-30 23:59:59');  
     }
     else  if($current_month>=7 && $current_month<=9)
     {
       $start_date = strtotime($current_year.'-07-01 00:00:00');
       $end_date = strtotime($current_year.'-09-30 23:59:59');
     }
     else  if($current_month>=10 && $current_month<=12)
     {
       $start_date = strtotime($current_year.'-10-01 00:00:00');
       $end_date = strtotime($current_year.'-12-31 23:59:59');
     }
```

Use this `$start_date` and  `$end_date` timestemp in Query as below :

```
$services= Service::find()
   ->select(['client.id as client_id'])
   ->joinWith('client')
   ->where([         
       'service.type' => Service::TYPE,
       'service.is_archived' => Service::ARCHIVED,])
   ->andWhere([
       'or',
       ['client_service.status' => ClientService::STATUS_NEGATIVE],
       ['between', 'client_service.created', $start_date, $end_date]
      ])
```